# ¿Problema al obtener datos con Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-axios

Tengo un formulario que al momento de dar click al botón ejecuta una función que consume un Api local simple que hice.

Mi duda es por que cuando le doy clik al botón por primera vez no toma los datos pero a la segunda vez si los toma, no entiendo alguien que me ayude el por que pasa esto.

ESTA ES LA FUNCION QUE SE EJECUTA AL DAR CLICK

```
  const[user,Setuser] = useState([]);


    async function Validar(){

        await axios.get("http://localhost/Crud/crud-app/src/Data/Api.php")
        .then((response)=>{

            Setuser(response.data);
            console.log(user);
            
        })
        
    }
```

ESTE ES EL BOTON

```
 <button type="button" onClick={()=>Validar()}>Iniciar sesion</button>
```

EN MI CONSOLA MUESTRA ESTO CUANDO DOY CLICK
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciones Hooks son **asincrónicas**, `SetUser` se ejecuta de forma async:

```
Setuser(response.data);
```

Hay que recordar, que estas funciones se registran en una lista de tareas y regresan resultados tiempo después:

```
//SetUser se ejecuta de forma async
Setuser(response.data);
//JS no espera por la funcion async, continua su ejecución
//por eso el primer console.log se ve vacío.
console.log(user);
```

Cuando se da click en el botón por primera vez, ya se tiene la variable `user` con sus atributos asignados en scope, esto se puede verificar de la siguiente forma:

```
  async function Validar(){
      //tu código
      
  }
  //monitorea el estado de tu variable, fuera de la funcion 
  //en el scope del componente funcional.
  console.log(user);
```

Se seguirá viendo ese `console.log` vacío cuando carge el componente, pues no tiene valor inicial, pero cuando se presione el botón, ya se tendrá la variable `user` con sus atributos asignados en scope, esto es porque la función Hook `setuser` registrada en la lista de espera, ya regresó y además, ejecuto el re-render del componente.

Por último, yo escogería transformar la función `Validar` a Promise, tal como lo recomienda el colega @Kroneaux Schneider.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ya entiendo un poco mejor. me gustaría que me ayudaras a ascender a los datos de ese JSON obtener un dato especifico el jsones este [
    {
        "user": "yosip",
        "password": 123
    }
] He intentado con user[0].user pero no funciona

Comment: Con `user[0].user` se pide acceso al primer elemento del arreglo **response.data**, estas seguro de que hay registros en esa posición? y si los hay, el user "yosip" esta en la primera posición?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que estás mezclando cosas...

Primero, puedes definir el `onClick` de una manera más sencilla:

```
 <button type="button" onClick={Validar}>Iniciar sesion</button>
 //                             ^ Sin función flecha
```

Después, en tu función `Validar` estás mezclando dos maneras de obtener la información: `async/await` y `resolve`. Una `Promise` tiene dos maneras de controlar: bien a través de obtener el resultado con el operador `await`, o bien esperar al callback `resolve` con la estructura `.then().catch()`. Decide cuál de los dos utilizar.

Para hacerlo con async/await:

```
async function Validar() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost/Crud/crud-app/src/Data/Api.php");
        Setuser(response.data);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Con Promise:

```
function Validar() {
    axios.get("http://localhost/Crud/crud-app/src/Data/Api.php")
      .then((response)=>{
        Setuser(response.data);
        console.log(user);
      });
}
```