# Console.log me devuelve undefined y un objeto... request axios react hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, javascript-objeto, react-hooks, requests

Buenas estoy armando un componente hook de react y al hacer una request con axios y manipulando la respuesta colocandola en el estado de mi componente me tira error por que me dice que no se puede manipular undefined... creo que el error podria orientarse un poco por lo que el console.log me devuelve en la consola(2 respuestas)- undefined- y el array

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import axios from 'axios';


export default function SelectFormCategory(){

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    async function getCategories(){
        const categories = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/categories')
        setData(categories.data)
    }
  console.log( data[0]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategories();
      }, []);
    return (
  <Select defaultValue={} options={} />        
    )}
```

que podría hacer para que ese undefined no me salga, poder manipular el array y poner de cada objeto su propiedad name dentro del select  "option" ? gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, lo que estas obteniendo es normal, el primer `log` viene `undefined` pues estas iniciando el estado de la variable `data` con un array vacío, luego se ejecuta la función asincrónica del hook, el componente se renderiza nuevamente, pero esta vez ya tienes datos en el scope para `data`, puedes revisar la siguiente [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414720/problema-al-obtener-datos-con-axios/414749#414749) para que despejes tus dudas, si te sirve vota por ella, esta es una pregunta muy común en la comunidad React SO, saludos

Comment: exacto tienes razon , el problema es que al querer manipular ese estado y querer colocarlo dentro del select el component se rompe porque toma primero el undefined...como podria hacer para una vez  obtenido ese estado lo pueda colocar en el select?

Comment: Prepare una respuesta, espero que sea de ayuda, Saludos

Comment: Justo edité la respuesta con unas mejoras e información adicional que puede ser de ayuda.

Comment: He agregado también un prototipo para el `select`, avísanos si tienes dudas o si lograste avanzar, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, lo que estas obteniendo es normal, el primer `log` viene `undefined` pues estas iniciando el estado de la variable `data` con un array vacío, por lo tanto `array[0]=undefined`.

Luego, se ejecuta la función asincrónica del hook, el componente se renderiza nuevamente, pero esta vez ya tienes datos en el scope para `data`.

Con respecto al `select`, se usa un nuevo Hook para definir la opción inicial y la función hanlder:

```
const [option, setOption] = React.useState("");
```

Luego, se decalara una constante `mySelect` para asignar la configuración del `select`, con su respectivo evento `onChange`; la función `map` crea dinámicamente las opciones del `select`, después se propagan con del operador **elipsis** (spread operator):

```
//prototipo select tag
const mySelect = <select onChange={onSelectOption} value={option || ''}>
                        {[...data.map((currentValue, index)=>(
                            <option value={currentValue} key={index}>
                            {currentValue}
                            </option>))
                         ]}
                  </select>;
```

Para la validación, puedes usar un **operador ternario**, para saber si el array `data` ya viene con datos o no. A continuación el componente completo:

```js
function App(){
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [option, setOption] = React.useState("");
  //useEffect configurado para correr solo una vez
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    //tu código async
    const tArray = ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]
    setData(tArray)
  }, []);
  //handler select
  function onSelectOption(e){
    const option = e.target.value;
    setOption(option);
  }
  //prototipo select tag
  const mySelect = <select onChange={onSelectOption} value={option || ''}>
                        {[...data.map((currentValue, index)=>(
                        <option value={currentValue} key={index}>
                        {currentValue}
                        </option>))]}
                      </select>;
  //llega 0 en el primer render
  //llega con datos en el re-render, despues de setData
  console.log(data.length)
  //validas con Ternary Operator
  return (
  (data.length === 0) ? "loading..." : <div>{mySelect}</div>)
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

La sintáxis del **Ternary operator** es:

> condition ? expression1 : expression2

Así es como quedo implementado:

```
//reemplaza h3-expression2 por tu select
 (data.length === 0) ? "loading..." : <div>{mySelect}</div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: muchisimas gracias , sabes que tuve muchos problemas con react-select y opte por hacerlo como lo has hecho tu, se me hizo mas practico manejar la informacion ... el react-select parece que me obligaba darle un atributo label a mis entidades para poder manejar los valores la verdad una lastima que tenga ese talon por que parece muy buena herramienta ... muchisimas gracias por tu ejemplo me sirvio para terminar mi componente y  sacar dudas teoricas

Comment: Que bien @gabrielcaballero, voy a revisar el `react-select` cuando pueda, yo tampoco lo he usado, si consideras que la respuesta fue de utilidad, no olvides votar  y aceptarla, para que otros usuarios puedan usar el ejemplo, suerte y salud!

Comment: Ya esta la respuesta como aceptada!, ahora para que ganes la medalla **Apoyador** y puntos, debes votar a favor, en la misma sección donde aceptaste, debes dar click en el icono up arrow (Esta respuesta es útil), saludos